# How to convert a custom type in Fsharp to JSON string?

Tags: json, serialization, f#

I have the following type:

```
type ResponseJsonOk = {
  ok : string;
}
```

I would like to generate the following JSON:

```
{"ok": "ok"}
```

I have created the following value:

```
let responseJsonOk: ResponseJsonOk = {  ok = "ok" }
```

Not sure how to convert it to JSON. Could not find documentation how I am supposed to be doing that with JsonValue from FSharp.Data.

Comment: If you are familiar with Newtonsoft.Json you can use that (or another library) - it will look something like `JsonConvert.Serialize(responseJsonOk)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @onemorecupofcoffee pointed out in a comment, you can use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
open Newtonsoft.Json

let str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject responseJsonOk
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use the native .NET library `System.Text.Json`.

```
open System.Text.Json

type jwtHeader = {
  typ: string
  alg: string
}
let exHeader = { typ = "JWT"; alg = "HS256" }

> JsonSerializer.Serialize exheader
val it: string = "{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}"
```